# HIGHCHART: HOW TO START TICK AT (0,0)

Tags: android, highcharts

Hi every one,
The chart **did not display** first tick at first day I wanted.

Below is my code:

> > //1week
> >
> > `series : [ {data : yValue,
> >     pointStart : Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),pointInterval : 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000} ]`

Comment: I want to display first tick at my **first date 2013/01/01** But first tick **was at 2012/12/28**, so the second one **was at 2013/01/04**. Could you give me some ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try `showFirstLabel: true` option and `startOnTick: true` option

The document is here:http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.showFirstLabel

This is an option can be used on both xAxis and yAxis

---

Updated:

Based on your description. I think the "startOfWeek" is taking effect. It automatically make the first tick of xAxis as Mondy then to your added dates. I don't know if there's a way to turn it off. You have two ways to make it display correctly:

1. provide your date and yValue together as key-values and pass it to chart all together instead of generating xAxis from option or
2. calculate the first day of your utcDate and set startOfWeek to the corresponding value (default is Monday => 1, and respectively 2 to 6, then 0 for Sunday)

Comment: It still display wrong, This link straightforward to my code: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byhex0k4V6rmSnlGdldwdlNOVjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: there is likely a shift here. In my thinking, the first tick will at **2013/01/01** because of UTC's setting, but, although i tried my best to find solution, first tick still at **2012/12/28**. My interval is 7 days, as the result, the second tick is at **2013/01/04**.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Monday is displayed first, I am going to try all your solutions, Thank you so much!